# How to set up a react blog page with text and code with syntax highlighting?

Tags: html, reactjs, django, django-models, blogs

I'm creating a blog with react frontend and Django backend. I'm not sure how to store the code snippets and text of the article in the database. If I store it together can I ignore the text when doing syntax highlighting. Or should I store the code snippets seperately from text for syntax highlighting.

Comment: Have you considered storing it as markdown?

Comment: or store as a text but display as markdown? There are some markdown display react components